# How to change bin size for each subplot when using Dataframe.plot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame that contains all numerical columns, where the range of the data differs considerably between columns. The code below provides a representative example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': np.random.randn(10000) * 20,
    'B': np.random.randn(10000) * 1000,
    'C': np.random.randn(10000) * 0.01,
    'D': np.random.randn(10000) * 300000,
    'E': np.random.randn(10000) * 500
})

axs = df.plot(kind = 'hist',subplots = True, bins = 10, layout = (2,3), figsize = (12,8), title = list(df.columns), sharex = False, sharey = True)

for i, ax in enumerate(axs.reshape(-1)):
    if i>= len(df.columns):
        break
    ax.set_xlim(df[df.columns[i]].min(),df[df.columns[i]].max())
    
plt.suptitle('Histograms for all features')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

When `df.plot` was called, the xlim range was automatically set to the range of the column with the largest numbers, which is why I added the **for** loop to solve that.

However, as you can see in the screenshot below, the bins are not correctly scaled.

[histograms with wrong bins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yayt.png)

I would like every subplot to display 10 bins, with each bin of the appropriate width for each histogram.
Is there a way to do that, either in the call to `df.plot` or accessing the Axes objects with some method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas [hist function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html#pandas.DataFrame.hist) instead.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': np.random.randn(10000) * 20,
    'B': np.random.randn(10000) * 1000,
    'C': np.random.randn(10000) * 0.01,
    'D': np.random.randn(10000) * 300000,
    'E': np.random.randn(10000) * 500
})

df.describe()

plt.figure();
df.hist(bins = 10,layout = (2,3),density = True, figsize = (12,8), sharex = False, sharey = False
);
```

Comment: Nice. Note that you should remove `plt.figure()` to avoid creating a dummy empty plot. You can set `sharey=True` and also `density=False` to be more similar to OP.  (Setting the titles don't seem to be supported.)